# On an ARM64 Windows system, how do I ensure access to specific WOW sections of the registry?

Tags: windows, powershell, registry, wmi

I want to write a PowerShell function that includes a parameter or argument that allows the caller to access any of the following "sections" of the Windows Registry.

---

I have this working on Intel x86 / AMD64 using the WMI StdRegProv and the __ProviderArchitecture named value, which accepts an integer 32 or 64.

See the following examples for how this works on Intel x86/AMD64:

- On a 64-bit (AMD64) Windows system when 64-bit registry is requested, a registry read to HKLM\SOFTWARE\Lenovo\DisplayName reads from HKLM\SOFTWARE\Lenovo\DisplayName whether the process is 32-bit or 64-bit.
- On a 64-bit (AMD64) Windows system when 32-bit registry is requested, a registry read to HKLM\SOFTWARE\Lenovo\DisplayName transparently reads from HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Lenovo\DisplayName whether the process is 32-bit or 64-bit.
- On a 32-bit (x86) Windows system when 32-bit registry is requested, a registry read to HKLM\SOFTWARE\Lenovo\DisplayName reads from HKLM\SOFTWARE\Lenovo\DisplayName as expected.
- On a 32-bit (x86) Windows system when 64-bit registry is requested, a registry read to HKLM\SOFTWARE\Lenovo\DisplayName generates an error (expected).

To see how I coded this for Intel x86/AMD64, see this Docs page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/requesting-wmi-data-on-a-64-bit-platform#example-forcing-wmi-to-access-the-32-bit-registry-hive-on-a-64-bit-computer

I have also pasted a copy of the example VBScript code on the Docs page here, in case the URL breaks in the future:

```
strComputer = "."
Const HKLM = &h80000002
Set objCtx = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemNamedValueSet")
objCtx.Add "__ProviderArchitecture", 32
objCtx.Add "__RequiredArchitecture", TRUE
Set objLocator = CreateObject("Wbemscripting.SWbemLocator")
Set objServices = objLocator.ConnectServer(strComputer,"root\default","","",,,,objCtx)
Set objStdRegProv = objServices.Get("StdRegProv") 

' Use ExecMethod to call the GetStringValue method
Set Inparams = objStdRegProv.Methods_("GetStringValue").Inparameters
Inparams.Hdefkey = HKLM
Inparams.Ssubkeyname = "Software\Microsoft\Wbem\CIMOM"
Inparams.Svaluename = "Logging"
set Outparams = objStdRegProv.ExecMethod_("GetStringValue", Inparams,,objCtx)

'Show output parameters object and the registry value HKLM\SOFTWARE\
WScript.Echo Outparams.GetObjectText_
WScript.Echo "WMI Logging is set to  " & Outparams.SValue
```

EDIT:
For more examples of how to do this on x86 / AMD64, see the following links:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3214643/2134110
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/52430223/2134110

And, I thought these were good examples for using PowerShell for non-registry WMI access on x86/AMD64:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/19130808/2134110
- https://serverfault.com/a/779062/283189

However, the focus of my question is not how to do this on x86/AMD64, but rather: how to do similar redirection on ARM64 systems. See below for specifics.

---

The problem I'm facing is that the __ProviderArchitecture named value accepts a integer with value 32 or 64, which becomes ambiguous on an ARM64 Windows system. For example, does 32 mean "x86" or does it mean "ARM" (ARM32)?

I would like to have the following functionality:

- AMD64 (64-bit Intel x86x64) systems:

  - On an AMD64 Windows system when AMD64 registry is requested, a registry read to HKLM\SOFTWARE\Lenovo\DisplayName reads from HKLM\SOFTWARE\Lenovo\DisplayName whether the process is x86 or AMD64.
  - On an AMD64 Windows system when x86 registry is requested, a registry read to HKLM\SOFTWARE\Lenovo\DisplayName transparently reads from HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Lenovo\DisplayName whether the process is x86 or AMD64.
  - On an AMD64 Windows system when ARM64 or ARM (ARM32) registry is requested, a registry read to HKLM\SOFTWARE\Lenovo\DisplayName generates an error (expected).
- x86 (32-bit Intel x86) systems:

  - On an x86 Windows system when x86 registry is requested, a registry read to HKLM\SOFTWARE\Lenovo\DisplayName reads from HKLM\SOFTWARE\Lenovo\DisplayName as expected.
  - On an x86 Windows system when AMD64, ARM64, or ARM (ARM32) registry is requested, a registry read to HKLM\SOFTWARE\Lenovo\DisplayName generates an error (expected).
- ARM64  systems:

  - On an ARM64 Windows system when ARM64 registry is requested, a registry read to HKLM\SOFTWARE\Lenovo\DisplayName reads from HKLM\SOFTWARE\Lenovo\DisplayName whether the process is ARM64, ARM (ARM32), x86, or AMD64.
  - On an ARM64 Windows system when x86 registry is requested, a registry read to HKLM\SOFTWARE\Lenovo\DisplayName transparently reads from HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Lenovo\DisplayName whether the process is ARM64, ARM (ARM32), x86, or AMD64.
  - On an ARM64 Windows system when ARM (ARM32) registry is requested, a registry read to HKLM\SOFTWARE\Lenovo\DisplayName transparently reads from HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOWAA32Node\Lenovo\DisplayName whether the process is ARM64, ARM (ARM32), x86, or AMD64.
  - On an ARM64 Windows system when AMD64 registry is requested, a registry read to HKLM\SOFTWARE\Lenovo\DisplayName transparently reads from HKLM\SOFTWARE(Placeholder, TBD upon 21H1 release)\Lenovo\DisplayName whether the process is ARM64, ARM (ARM32), x86, or AMD64.
- ARM (ARM32) systems:

  - On an ARM (ARM32) Windows system when ARM (ARM32) registry is requested, a registry read to HKLM\SOFTWARE\Lenovo\DisplayName reads from HKLM\SOFTWARE\Lenovo\DisplayName when the process is ARM (ARM32).
  - On an ARM (ARM32) Windows system when x86, ARM64, or AMD64 registry is requested, a registry read to HKLM\SOFTWARE\Lenovo\DisplayName generates an error (expected). Note that Windows RT's (ARM32 Windows 8/8.1) registry includes HKLM\Wow6432Node, but it lacks an x86 Windows-on-Windows emulation layer.

Does anyone know how I can pull this off in PowerShell? It doesn't seem that the StdRegProv has granular process architecture designators, but maybe there is a parameter that is not documented.

---

UPDATE: I have looked into .NET-native ways to do what I am trying to do, and I came across the links below. Basically, there is a .NET Microsoft.Win32.RegistryView type that works very similarly to the WMI __ProviderArchitecture named value. That is, RegistryView is set to either Registry32 or Registry64, which are ambiguous on an AMD64 system.

References:

- https://edi.wang/post/2019/3/4/read-and-write-windows-registry-in-net-core
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registryview?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: [I edited the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65361023/2) to try and make the question less broad but as you insist on rolling it back this question will probably be closed. Tagging both [tag:powershell] and [tag:vbscript] is not considered helpful. Either ask about a [tag:powershell] problem or a [tag:vbscript] one not both.

Comment: Does this answer the question? [OS architecture detection script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27648165) (if it was VBScript related).

Comment: @Lankymart I reverted to PowerShell tags only. But to be clear, I would accept a VBScript answer as well if it were not for your comment. Unfortunately, the link that you provided doesn't help in this case -- I know how to detect both the OS and process architecture, but am stuck trying to force access to specific sections of the registry.

Comment: You realise that the registry access points are the same on a 32 and 64-bit OS right? It only "changes" on a 64-bit system when you need to access the 32-bit subsystem. The `WOW6432Node` is purely for access to the 32-bit subsystem registry hive on 64-bit systems.

Comment: How are you performing these test are you using something like `regread` from the command line or are you using WMI, if so share the code? It's difficult to reproduce as you don't show the commands you used while testing.

Comment: @Lankymart there is an example in the MS Docs page that I linked: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/requesting-wmi-data-on-a-64-bit-platform#example-forcing-wmi-to-access-the-32-bit-registry-hive-on-a-64-bit-computer - I'll add it to the post. You could take the same example and modify the __ProviderArchitecture to 64 to force 64 bit access even on a 32-bit process..

Comment: Forcing the `__ProviderArchitecture` doesn’t change what the OS architecture actually is.

Comment: Are you sure you’re running these scripts with the correct architecture process? For example the 32 bit `cscript.exe` on a 64 bit Windows OS should be from `%windir%\SysWOW64\cscript.exe`.

Comment: @Lankymart yes, that's exactly how I would run a 32-bit x86 cscript process when testing on a AMD64, ARM/ARM32, or ARM64 OS.

Comment: To the folks voting to close this question - may I ask why? Is something unclear?

Comment: Are you aware of [Registry Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/registry-redirector)?

Comment: @JosefZ yes... the Registry Redirector is the underlying Windows functionality that I am referencing in my question.

Comment: Progress update: I submitted a MS Docs pull request to improve inclusivity of ARM architectures. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/win32/pull/713 -- more to come!